# Generating Metrics for hierarchical data in Python

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I have the following dataset in a CSV file:

```
continent, country, city, address
north america, usa, new york, 100 Penn Plaza
north america, usa, new york, 202 Barnes Ave
north america, usa, seattle, 303 Pike Place Ave
north america, canada, ottawa, 400 Marshall Blvd
north america, canada, ottawa, 303 Lonely Marsh Rd
north america, chile, calama, 1001 Los Lucas St
```

Now, let's say I wanted to generate two key things here.

1. How many cities are associated to each country and what those cities are (Showing association to the respective country)
2. How many streets fall under each specific city and what those streets are (Showing association to the respective city)
3. Generating this in a format that is somewhat consumable

I could see the metrics being pretty easy to derive if I were to convert this into a Python dict, but as for how I store the data associations between the parent/child objects into something like a CSV seems to be the tedious part.

How would you approach this situation?